# Sequence of Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Be $a_{1}=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}$, for all $n\ge1$. It is $(a_{n})$ a  Cauchy sequence?

Attempt:  I know that the term $a_{n+1}$ depends on term $a_{n}$ and consequently $a_{n}$ depends on $a_{n-1}$. Then outlined the sequence $(a_{n})=(1,1+\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{2}{5},1+\frac{5}{12},...,1+\frac{1}{1+a_{n-1}},...)$.

I believe it has to be the application of the definition of Cauchy sequence, but tou do not know. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

The terms follows the pattern
$$
1, 1+\frac{1}{1+1},1+\frac{1}{1+1+\frac{1}{1+1}},1+\frac{1}{1+1+\frac{1}{1+1+\frac{1}{1+1}}}
$$
Then the sequence is the convergent of the following continued fraction
$$[1,2,2,2,2,2,...].$$
That is: the sequence converges to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: it converges to $\sqrt{2}$ as $L = 1 + \dfrac{1}{L+1} \to L = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems for a formula for the difference between two successive convergents of a continued fraction which can be used to prove the sequence of convergents is Cauchy. (Note: "convergent" means a term of the sequence not its limit.)

Comment: Sorry, I calculate wrong the number. Thanks! @NotALoner