# proving convergence of $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> $a_1=1.$ $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_{n}}$

**Prove that the sequence is convergent.**

I'm trying to prove the convergence of this sequence but having trouble. At first I thought this might be a monotone sequence since then I can try monotone convergence theorem to prove its convergence.

But after checking some terms, I realized it seemed the sequence is oscillating. So I'm not sure how to prove the convergence of this sequence.

Thanks.

Comment: The sequence _is_ oscillating, but you should be able to show monotonicity of $a_{2n}$ and (separately) $a_{2n+1}$.

Comment: This sequence is Cauchy sequence so it converges

Comment: Oh this is cauchy sequence? I will have to check it out...

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1304685, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1967764, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1273096, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436316 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%3D1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Ba_%7Bn%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence is a Cauchy sequence so it converges.

First you see $a_n>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ from recursive relation.  [$a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}$ is defined to added positive terms]

Second since $a_n>0$ thus $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{1+a_n} \leq 2 $

Now consider
\begin{align}
|a_{n+1} - a_n| = \left| \frac{1}{1+a_n} - \frac{1}{1+a_{n-1}} \right|
 = \frac{|a_n - a_{n-1}|}{(1+a_n)(1+a_{n-1})} \leq \frac{1}{4} | a_n - a_{n -1}|
\end{align}
and this is cauchy sequence. [Series with this form is called contractive and after repeatively apply the same procedure continuing to $|a_2-a_1|$, and by Squeeze theorem you can easily guess $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence]

In $\mathbb{R}$ cauchy sequence implies convergences so it converges. Then by taking limits $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = \alpha$ we have $\alpha^2 = 2$ and from $a_n>0$, $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: thanks a lot! Cauchy sequence is quite useful as always...

Comment: You need $a_n \ge 1$ for the last estimate, not $a_n > 0$. (The question is a multiple duplicate, though).

Answer (score 1):

A method often useful with oscillating sequences: Let $b_n=|(a_n)^2-2|.$ Then $$0\le b_{n+1}=\frac {b_n}{(1+a_n)^2}\le \frac {b_n}{4} $$ because $1+a_n\ge 2$ by induction on $n$.

So $b_n$ decreases to  $0$. So $(a_n)^2\to 2$ with each $a_n>0.$

The motivation for the "$2$" in the definition of $b_n$ is that IF $a_n$ converges to a limit $L$ then $L=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1+\frac {1}{1+a_n}=1+\frac {1}{1+L},$ implying $L^2=2.$